# "Points movement" or "Movement of points" or "Movement of the points"

Tags: grammar

I am working on a scientific paper and there is a graph in it showing how some points are moved.... The reviewer suggest me to change "Points movement" to "Movement of points". But I still could not get it why "Movement of points" is more preferable?

1. Isn't it the shorter the better?
2. Why not "Movement of the points"? (I feel quite confused too to see: some people use "Response to reviewers", some use "Response to the reviewers"!)

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "points movement" **or** by "movement of points". Are these physical points that have been physically moved? Or points on a display that shift position under some mathematical transformation? Or rhetorical points made in speechs that shift their structure as the policy matures? Or what? Context is everything. Especially in science, where the impulse is to **leave in** words if they might clarify, rather than to leave them out because of some sense that shorter is better. Shorter is almost always muddier, as the questions here demonstrate.

Comment: That's why you don't have a Rights Bill over there, possibly? And imagine Mordor's 'Mountain of Doom' having to suffer 'Doom Mountain'.

Comment: @JohnLawler It's "points on a display that shift position under some mathematical transformation".

Comment: Then why are you calling them "points" at all? They're clearly numeric values of something that you are talking about in the paper, and they should be labelled the same as the values they're displaying. Unless you're a punctologist, of course, in which case points are the focus of research.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. These points on the display have their physical meaning. And OKAY, you want to know more detail, that's fine! Here it is: in finite element or finite volume analysis, the computational space needs to be discretized first, we call it mesh or grid, it has numerous mesh points or grid points. Now we want to do some mesh deformation/transformation, which means the grid points need to be moved (of cause according to some math transformation). Just google image the "dynamic mesh" and you will find it.

Comment: The usual way of expressing this in English would be ***point movement*** or ***point movements*** rather than ***points movement***, even if multiple points are being moved.

Comment: @PeterShor Are you saying "point movement" is better than "movement of points"? In this specific context, or in general?

Comment: Ah, you **are** a punctologist, then -- i.e, _point_ is a term of art in the theory, in something like its geometric sense, though no doubt not in a geometrically simple space. Thanks for the context.

Comment: "Points movement" is basically unacceptable. Both "point movement" and "movement of points" are fine; I'd have to know more about the sentence you're using it in to know which one I'd prefer, but there would generally be only a slight difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has hauled a rich bounty of useful comments. Let me summarize them for you.

What @Edwin Ashworth is telling you : it is far more usual / conventional / preferable to employ the *[**Passive Voice**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice)* when you're writing a title for a graph. The passive voice certainly sounds more formal and proper in your usage context.

What Professor Lawler is telling you : the "points" represent some data, so you might also choose to better inform your reader via the title of your graph about what those points really mean - something like *Discretized Computational Space:Mesh Transformation*, for instance.

To further answer your question: 1) No, shorter isn't always better. By choosing to communicate faster all the time, we oftentimes run the risk of not communicating at all, or not communicating effectively enough. 2) My personal preference would be to use *Response to reviewers.*

Comment: Thanks. So are you saying grammarly they are all "correct", it is just "movement of points" and "Response to (without-the) reviewers" sound better for a native speaker?

Comment: I hadn't realised that's what I was saying – I don't usually make mistakes like that. @Daniel: I'd look up 'attributive noun' threads here, and bear in mind that they are very seldom used in the plural form (_sports_ centre being an obvious exception). Also that the form using _of_ **is** longer, but may be preferred in individual cases for clarity or more usually just because it is considered to sound better (my examples above). In this case, I'd seriously consider 'displacement' anyway.